# problema para detener addEventListener scroll en javascript

Tags: javascript, vanilla

mi problema es que ejecuto un evento para detentar cuando el scroll se detenga y veo si esta al final de la pagina, luego hago que aparecieron mis nuevas imagenes y todo bien hasta ese punto pero si me voy a cualquier otra parte del menu, se sigue provocó el evento de scroll dándome errores por todos lados y lo logro detener, si me pueden ayudar, tengo ya el día entero buscando soluciones y nada, aqui les dejo el codigo.

```
   const onScrollStop = callback => {
        let isScrolling;
        window.addEventListener(
          'scroll',
          e => {


            
            clearTimeout(isScrolling);
            isScrolling = setTimeout(() => {
              callback();
            }, 150);
          },
          false
        );
      };


      onScrollStop(() => {
       

        let element = document.querySelector('#pag_body');
      
        let tamano_total = element.offsetHeight;
    
       let recorrido = window.scrollY;
    
       let tamano_pantalla = window.innerHeight;
    
    if(detener_scroll!=true){
       if(tamano_pantalla+recorrido+1>=tamano_total){


        if(cantidad_min==cantidad_max){
         
            return;
        }else{
         
        content_items_busqueda(cantidad_min);
//favoritos()
        }
       }
   } 



      });
```

lo que necesito es que se deje de ejecutar el llamado a evento de scroll para que no me de mas errroes

Comment: queres que el evento se desactive al llegar al final de la pagina?

Comment: te explico, digamos que tengo en el menu la seccion de items, que es donde se ejecuta este evento y se van mostrando los items y luego paso a la parte del menu de favoritos, donde ya no necesito que este evento se ejecute, pero se me sigue ejecutando cada vez que hago scroll y sigue llamando a la funcion que le tengo dentro y me da error, lo que quiero es saber como desactivarlo, lei que se podia con removeEventListener pero no lo logro desactivar

Comment: agrega tu html y css asi puedo replicar tu error

Comment: asi cualquiera que te quiera ayudar puede copiar tu codigo.

Comment: amigo pero es que no es necesario algun css o html aqui, igual voy a ver si elaboro algo como de ejemplo por que el original donde estoy trabajando es un poco confuso por que tiene otras cosas que no irian al caso.